# Form appear behind everything?

Tags: vb.net

I'm developing a project on the .NET platform(VB.NET), and noticed after nearly ready maybe a bug of Visual Studio 2010. When I click to open the Form2 through Form3 it appears behind the main Form1 and not in front it should usually be. I searched a lot in various foruns and found nothing about it.

For ease of understanding the problem I'm providing the [download link](https://www.sendspace.com/file/lm5iez) containing the program and code.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You don't need to hide `Me`, you can simply show `Form2` using `ShowDialog()` and this way it will be shown above all other forms.

Comment: Instead of a link to your project, you should post the relevant parts of code here. Like the edit I did on your question based on your download link.

Comment: Read the tags - Visual Studio: *Do not use this tag unless you have a specific question about Visual Studio...*

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to Form 2 and Form 3 at the end of the load event

```
ME.BringToFront
```

Answer (score 0):

Rob, it don't work and I found a kludge.

Follow the link:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pt-BR/e5a74745-83a3-40e6-a558-c8aae4ac3938/form-abre-atrs-do-form-principal?forum=vsvbasicpt

Thanks